# Casting SomeType** to SomeType*[] and vice versa

Tags: c++, swig

I really need to this specifically as I am using SWIG and need to make a cast to match the function definition.

The function definition accepts

```
SomeType const * const variable_name[]
```

Also, another question would be-
How to allocate memory to

```
SomeType * variable[] = <??? using new or malloc >
```

for `x` entries?

Edit:

I have searched quite a lot, but I keep stumbling into post which allocate memory to `SomeType**` using new `SomeType*[x]` i.e.

```
SomeType** variable = new SomeType*[x];
```

Can you please tell me a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The function wants an array of *pointers*.

The statement:

```
SomeType * variable[];
```

Is not valid syntax.

You will need:

```
SomeType * * variable;
```

Declares a pointer to a pointer of `SomeType`.

You will need to perform memory allocation in two steps.
First, allocate the array of pointers:

```
variable = new SomeType * [/* some quantity */];
```

Remember, the above statement only allocates room for the pointers.  The memory contents is still not initialized.

Secondly, allocate pointers to the objects.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < some_quantity; ++i)
{
  variable[i] = new SomeType;
}
```

When deleting, delete the contents of the array before the array:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < some_quantity; ++i)
{
  delete variable[i];
}
delete[] variable;
```

Comment: Compilation error at your 1st line - storage size of 'variable' isn't known

Comment: @rents, Thanks for the review.  I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The function definition accepts
>
> ```
> SomeType const * const variable_name[]
> ```

I'm no expert in C++, but if the declaration of arrays in function parameters is the same as in C then this is a synonym for the following type:

```
SomeType const * const * variable_name
```

That is, an array in a function parameter *is really a pointer*. Your book should have explained this early on.

---

> I have searched quite a lot, but I keep stumbling into post which allocate memory to SomeType** using new SomeType*[x] i.e.
>
> ```
> SomeType** variable = new SomeType*[x];
> ```
>
> Can you please tell me a way to do this?

You could indeed allocate a `SomeType const * const *` using similar code to that, so you've answered your own question. I assume you could also use an `std::vector<SomeType const * const>` like so:

```
std::vector<SomeType const * const> *foo = new std::vector<SomeType const * const>();
/* XXX: Add some items to the vector */
SomeType const * const *bar = &foo[0];
```

This would be useful if you're not sure how many items `foo` should contain, and you expect it to grow.

---

I don't understand why people don't read books anymore. It's the fastest and cheapest (if you consider the cost of man hours) way to learn correctly from a reputable figure.